# How to get a list of groups from OpenShift

Tags: openshift

The [OpenShift documentation](https://docs.openshift.org/latest/admin_guide/manage_users.html) is covering how to get users and identities, but not groups. `oc adm groups` allows one to create a new group, add and remove users, but there doesn't seem to be a way to list all existing groups.

Is there an other way to get the groups already known to the system?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you tried `oc get groups` (as a cluster admin)? This should provide you with the list of groups and users within those groups.